# Magento 2 - Create Admin Grid and show Custom Module list with Enable/Disable option

Tags: magento2, module, admin, grid

I have been working on custom module in Magento 2 which will perform some kind of calculations on frontend. Now I need to port those modules into Admin, where user can see menu and module list. Clicking on that list, admin can see all modules developed so far under **Vendor** namespace. Below is the code to create admin menu.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
       <add id="Vendor_Namespace::helloworld" 
                title="Helloworld" 
                module="Vendor_Namespace" 
                sortOrder="51" 
                resource="Vendor_Namespace::helloworld"/>

       <add id="Vendor_Namespace::modulelist" 
                title="Concrete Calculator" 
                module="Vendor_Namespace" 
                sortOrder="1" 
                action="Vendor_Namespace/modulelist" 
                resource="Vendor_Namespace::modulelist" 
                parent="Vendor_Namespace::helloworld"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

[image: Module List]

1. How do I create `Admin grid` where clicking on `Module List` shows all
   the modules developed ?
2. How can I add `enable/disable` button to any module, so that based on
   selection, that module is shown/hidden on frontend ?
3. Do I need to create admin module separately or can I add `menu.xml`
   in custom module ?

P.S. Is it necessary to create `SQL` script for admin grid? The purpose is to show all custom module list in Admin and enable/disable.